# getting distinct rows based on two column values

Tags: t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get distinct rows from a temporary table and output them to an aspx page. I am trying to use the value of one column and get the last entry made into that column.

I have been trying to use `inner join` and `max()`. However i have been unsuccessful.

Here is the code i have been trying to do it with.

```
Declare @TempTable table    (
    viewIcon nvarchar(10),
    tenderType nvarchar(20),
    diaryIcon int,
    customerName nvarchar(100),
    projectName nvarchar(100),
    diaryEntry nvarchar(max),
    diaryDate nvarchar(20),
    pid nvarchar(20)

    )

insert into @TempTable(
    viewIcon,
    tenderType,
    diaryIcon,
    customerName,
    projectName,
    diaryEntry ,
    diaryDate ,
    pid 
    )

select p.viewicon, 
    p.[Tender Type],
    1 diaryicon,
    c.[Customer Name],
    co.[Last Project],
    d.Action,
    co.[Diary Date],
    p.PID
    From Projects2 p Inner Join 
(select distinct Pno, max(convert(date,[date of next call],103)) maxdate from ProjectDiary group by Pno
    ) td on  p.PID = td.Pno
Inner Join contacts3 co on co.[Customer Number] = p.[Customer Number]
Inner Join Customers3 c on p.[Customer Number] = c.[Customer Number]
Inner Join ProjectDiary d on td.Pno = d.Pno 
Where CONVERT(Date, co.[Diary Date], 103) BETWEEN GETDATE()-120 AND GETDATE()-60

DECLARE @contactsTable TABLE
    (pid nvarchar(200), 
    diaryDate date)

insert into @contactsTable (t.pid, t.diarydate)
select distinct pid as pid, MAX(CONVERT(DATE, diaryDate, 103)) as diaryDate from @        TempTable t group by pid
DECLARE @tempContacts TABLE
(pid nvarchar(200))

insert into @tempContacts(pid)
select pid from @contactsTable
DECLARE @tempDiaryDate TABLE (diaryDate date)
insert into @tempDiaryDate(diaryDate)
select distinct MAX(CONVERT(DATE, diaryDate, 103)) from @TempTable

select t.* from @TempTable t inner join (select distinct customerName, M    AX(CONVERT(DATE, diaryDate, 103)) AS diaryDate from @TempTable group by customerName) tt on t    t.customerName=t.customerName
where t.pid not in 
(select Pno from ProjectDiary where convert(date,[Date Of Next Call],103) > GETDATE())
and t.viewIcon <> '098'
and t.viewIcon <> '163'
and t.viewIcon <> '119'
and t.pid in (select distinct pid from @tempContacts)
and CONVERT(DATE, t.diaryDate, 103) in (select distinct CONVERT(DATE, diaryDate, 103) f    rom @tempDiaryDate)
order by CONVERT(DATE, tt.diaryDate, 103)
```

I am trying to get all the distinct customerName's using the max date to determine which record it uses.

Comment: Soo unclear.  "I am trying to use the value of one column and get the last entry made into that column."  One column - we have to figure out which one.  Define last entry.

Comment: im trying to get the latest date entry that has been made using the diaryDate and return the last entry that has been made for that customer. @Blam

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery.  Without going through your entire sql statement, the general idea is:

```
 Select [Stuff]
 From table t
 Where date = (Select Max(Date) from table
               where customer = t.customer)
```

Comment: That still returns the same result set as my statement.